# vaadin-grid cellClassNameGenerator doesn't render classes

Tags: lit-element, vaadin-grid

I'm trying to use the cellClassNameGenerator but no matter how I alter it, it doesn't add the class names to the cell elements in the HTML markup.

both https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/html-examples/grid-styling-demos

and https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/grid

don't seem to work, including adding the `[part~="cell"]` to the beginning of the CSS class name

```
import { css, customElement, html, LitElement, property } from 'lit-element';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-sort-column';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid';
import {EnvironmentContentBuildsApiModel} from "../dorc-refdata-api/models";
import {GridColumnElement} from "@vaadin/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-column";
import {GridItemModel} from "@vaadin/vaadin-grid";

@customElement('env-builds')
export class EnvBuilds extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Array }) builds:  EnvironmentContentBuildsApiModel[] = [];


  static get styles() {
    return css`
       .success {
        background-color: #90EE90;
      }

      .failure {
        background-color: #F08080;
      }
    `;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <vaadin-grid .items="${this.builds}"         
        theme="compact"
        height-by-rows
        .cellClassNameGenerator="${this.cellClassNameGenerator}">
      <vaadin-grid-sort-column header="Component Name" path="ComponentName" resizable>
      </vaadin-grid-sort-column>
      <vaadin-grid-sort-column header="Request Details" path="RequestDetails" resizable>
      </vaadin-grid-sort-column>
      <vaadin-grid-sort-column header="Update Date" path="UpdateDate" resizable>
      </vaadin-grid-sort-column>
      <vaadin-grid-sort-column header="Status" path="State" resizable>
      </vaadin-grid-sort-column>
  </vaadin-grid>
    `;
  }

  cellClassNameGenerator(_: GridColumnElement, model: GridItemModel){
    const item = model.item as EnvironmentContentBuildsApiModel;
    let classes = '';
    if (item.State === 'Complete') {
      classes += ' success';
    } else if (item.State === 'Failed') {
      classes += ' failure';
    }
    return classes;
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated?

Comment: The relevant documentation from Vaadin's site is here https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/grid/#styling-rows-and-columns

Comment: For me it looks like your class name generator is set correctly, but you are not adding the css via style module for shadow dom, thus css not getting applied. The classnames will be added in the internal html structure.

Comment: Is there an example of the style module somewhere?

Comment: So I finally found the answer to this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037749/how-to-style-the-vaadin-grid-header